# python/pandas linear programming/optimization challenge

Tags: python, optimization, pandas, linear-programming

So, I have an optimization problem that can perhaps be solved by linear programming (with `PuLP`?). My experience with this line of work is limited so perhaps another solution would be better.

The problem is as follows:

There are 37 items that need to be bought. Each item must be bought in a specific quantity, in a specific color.
For each item I have a variable number of stores that sell that item. There are about 8000 stores that combined sell the 37 items. There's not a single store that sells all 37 items. Each store has a variable quantity of that item available (if it is available) and a variable price. Also, each store has a minimum-buy amount.

In python I have two dataframes that should have all the information that I need. (store names are 'blurred')

```
wanted.head()
    item_color_id   item_id item_qty
0   86              21837   1
1   5               2431    2
2   11              2444    6
3   11              2476    4
4   3               2654    2

stores.head()
    item_color_id   item_id store_min_buy   store_name  store_price store_qty
0   86              21837   20.00           fda         0.18        100
1   86              21837   10.00           asdfa       0.52        89
2   86              21837   10.00           ghsde       0.55        64
3   86              21837   9.14            j5rs        0.41        31
4   86              21837   10.00           pjvds       0.44        26
```

The `stores` dataframe is already preprocessed so it does not contain any NaN values. Note that `store_min_buy` is the minimum amount of money that needs to be spend in that store.

The challenge is to minimize the cost of buying the 37 items. In addition to that I need the actual solution: Which items need to be bought from which stores.

Comment: Does color mean anything special or can we treat a combination of item id and color id as a new unique item? Does the store_min_buy apply to just the one thing or across the sum of all the things you buy at this store? What does it even mean that there's a min_buy of 9.14, can I buy 9 and 14% of an item somehow?

Comment: @harold I'm sorry for the confusion. To your first question: yes, the combination of item_id and color_id makes a new unique item. `store_min_buy` is the minimum amount of money need to be spend in that store. So a min_buy of 9.14 means that at least 9.14 euro/dollar need to be spend at that store.

Answer (score 2):

The min_buy constraint is a bit annoying, the rest is more obvious.

So have some decision variables:

```
x[i,j] = number of item i to buy at store j
u[j]   = store j is used at all
```

Then the obvious constraint:

```
sum(x[i,any]) >= wanted[i]  (>= because the min_buy constraint may force you to buy extra)
```

The min_buy constraint. Well this is annoying, because it's sort of like a conditional constraint.

```
sum(x[any,j]) <= M * u[j]  (ban u[j]=0 if some item is bought here)
min_buy[j] * u[j] <= sum(x[i,j] * price[i]) (force buying enough)
```

You can transform that to a legal constraint format the obvious way.
M is some big number, big enough that the constraint will be always satisfied if a store is used (so at least as big as the maximum number of items you might but there).

I don't really like this model. The linear phase will abuse that M as much as it can, and probably trivially satisfy the last two constraints by choosing `u` tiny but nonzero. That will cause a lot of grief in the integer phase because it means the fractional solution will probably underestimate the cost by a lot.